# Use Fold and If to define "remove three repetitions"

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

I am working on the text **Programming with Mathematica** by Paul Wellin. I some exercise is asked to define the following function using `If` in conjunction with `Map` or `Fold`.
[image]

I tried using `Fold` without success because of don't know well which expresion in `Fold[expr, a, list]` to use. I made my own version using `For` as follows

```
remove3Repetitions[lis_] := Module[{positions = {}, lis2, i = 1},
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[lis] - 2, i++,
   If[lis[[i]] == lis[[i + 1]] && lis[[i + 1]] == lis[[i + 2]],
     positions = Append[positions, {i}];
     ];
   ];
  lis2 = Delete[lis, positions]
  ]
```

This works fine, for example,

```
In[177]:= remove3Repetitions[{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1}]

Out[177]= {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}
```

But, using the Higher order functions `Fold` or `Map` may be a better approach. The text ask for this. I would like any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** If you *have to* use `Fold` and `If`:

```
ClearAll[shortenRepetitions]
shortenRepetitions[k_] := Fold[If[{#2} == Union[#[[-(k - 1) ;;]]], #, 
      Flatten[{#, #2}]] &, #[[;; k - 1]], #[[k ;;]]] &;

shortenRepetitions[3]@{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1}
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}
> ```

```
shortenRepetitions[3]@{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1}
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1}
> ```

```
shortenRepetitions[4]@{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1}
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

Alternative ways:

**2.** using [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html):

```
ClearAll[shortenRepetitions2]
shortenRepetitions2[k_] := Flatten[Split[#][[All, ;; UpTo[k - 1]]]] &;

shortenRepetitions2[3][{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1}]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}
> ```

**3.** using  [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html):

```
ClearAll[shortenRepetitions3]
shortenRepetitions3[k_] :=  SequenceReplace[{Repeated[x_, {k, ∞}]} :> 
     Sequence @@ ConstantArray[x, k - 1]] ;

shortenRepetitions3[3][{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1}]
```

> ```
>   {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

Only one triple

```
list = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1};
```

Using `SubsetReplace` (new in 12.1) and `SequenceCases`

```
SubsetReplace[list, # -> Splice @ Most @ #]& @
 First @ SequenceCases[list, {x_, x_, x_}]
```

{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}

**2.**

More than one triple

```
list = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4};

Fold[
 SubsetReplace[#1, {#2, #2, #2} -> Sequence[#2, #2]]&,
 list,
 SequenceCases[list, {x_, x_, x_} :> x]]
```

{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4}

**3.**

More generally

```
list = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4};

Fold[
 SubsetReplace[#1, {Repeated[#2, {3, Infinity}]} :> Sequence[#2, #2]] &,
 list,
 SequenceCases[list, {Repeated[x_, {3, Infinity}]} :> x]]
```

{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4}

**4.**

For the first two cases we can also use

```
list = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4};

Delete[list, Map[List @* First] @ SequencePosition[list, {x_, x_, x_}]]
```

{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4}

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1};

l2 = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4};

l3 = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4};
```

---

Another way to do this using `DeleteElements`:

```
remove3Repetitions[l_List] := Module[{patt, del},
  patt = s : {Repeated[x_, {3, ∞}]} :> {Splice@{Length@s[[3 ;;]]},s[[1]]};
  del = Rule @@ Transpose@Cases[patt]@Split[l];
  DeleteElements[l, del]]

remove3Repetitions /@ {l1, l2, l3} // Column
```

*Results*:

[image]